# Simple text parsing library

Tags: python

I have a method that takes addresses from the web, and therefore, there are many known errors like:

```
123 Awesome St, Pleasantville, NY, Get Directions
```

Which I want to be:

```
123 Awesome St, Pleasantville, NY
```

Is there a web service or Python library that can help with this?  It's fine for us to start creating a list of items like ", Get Directions" or a more generalized version of that, but I thought there might be a helper library for this kind of textual analysis.

Comment: Are the addresses themselves always in the same format?  Its just the trailing stuff that is bothering you?

Comment: So, you're looking for a natural-language address parser?

Comment: Would custom Regex's be a good solution?

Comment: This is a hard problem. How do you know if a piece of text is _not_ part of an address? You first need a way of differentiating between valid and invalid data. If the criteria for invalid data are fuzzy, you have a problem. It *might* be possible to write a simple solution for this, depending on specifics, but there is no simple way to solve it for the general case.

Comment: In my situation, I have an address and there are some known problems for which I can begin to build a regex.  I'm looking for scaffolding that's more extensible than what I'm doing now for the two known bad strings, 'Get Directions' and 'Multiple Locations' with an optional comma prepended:  re.sub(r'(?:, )?(Get Directions|Multiple Locations)', '', '123 Awesome St, New York, NY, Get Directions, Multiple Locations')

Comment: @mark it's just the trailing stuff that's bothering me for now

Comment: @matt Yes, a natural-language address parser would be fantastic.  If Google correctly understood that 'Get Directions' never stands for an actual address, then this wouldn't be a problem.  I'm open to a web service also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If the address contains one of those bad strings, walk backwards till you find another non-whitespace character. If the character is one of your separators, say `,` or `:`, drop everything from that character onwards. If it's a different character, drop everything *after* that character.</strike>

Make a list of known bad strings. Then, you could take that list and use it to build a gigantic regex and use `re.sub()`.

This is a naive solution, and isn't going to be particularly performant, but it does give you a clean way of adding known bad strings, by adding them to a file called `.badstrings` or similar and building the list from them.

Note that if you make bad choices about what these bad strings are, you will break the algorithm. But it should work for the simple cases you describe in the comments.

**EDIT:** Something like this is what I mean:

```
import re

def sanitize_address(address, regex):
    return regex.sub('', address)

badstrings = ['get directions', 'multiple locations']
base_regex = r'[,\s]+('+'|'.join(badstrings)+')'
regex = re.compile(base_regex, re.I)
address = '123 Awesome St, Pleasantville, NY, Get Directions'
print sanitize_address(address, regex)
```

which outputs:

```
123 Awesome St, Pleasantville, NY
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex that will parse either one.  If you have other examples, I can change the current Regex to work for it

`(?<address>(?:[0-9]+\s+(?:\w+\s?)+)+)[,]\s+(?<city>(?:\w+\s?)+)[,]\s+(?<state>(?:\w+\s?)+)(?:$|[,])`

this will even work for addresses that are in similar format to mine (1234 North 1234 West, Pleasantville, NY)

Comment: Thanks.  This is too brittle for what I want however.  I just want to get rid of known bad strings from an otherwise fine address.  Google Maps takes care of semi-normal address string once I preprocess it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the task is impossible to do with a high degree of confidence unless the data is in a fixed format, or you have a gigantic address database to make matches against.

You could *possibly* get away with having a list of countries, and then a rule set per country that you use. The American rule set could include a list of states, cities and postal codes and a pattern to find street addresses. You would then drop anything that isn't either a state, city postal code or looks like a street address.

You'd still drop things that should be a part of an address though, at least with  Swedish addresses, that can include just the name of a farm instead of a street and number. If US country side addresses are the same there is just no way to know what is a part of an address and what isn't unless you have access to a database with all US addresses. :-)

Comment: I'm not looking for an address parser.  I'm looking to cleanse addresses of a small set of known problems before forwarding them to Google Maps.

Comment: Wait, what you are *not* looking to analyze the text? That's what you say in the question you know... :-)